# How to express this with jOOQ "Select alias.*, otherAlias.Column From .."

Tags: sql, postgresql, scala, jooq

I am trying to use jOOQ to dynamically construct queries. So far it is going really well, but now I stumbled upon a case that I can not seem to express.

This is a simplified version of the query I want to generate:

```
Select alias.*, otherAlias.aColumn as aAlias  
From table as alias
inner join otherTable as otherAlias
on alias.someColumn = otherAlias.someOtherColumn
Where otherAlias.someOtherColumn in (????????)
```

My problem is that i cannot seem to express the **SELECT** part how I need it. If I just use:

```
.select() -> I get select *
.select(alias.fields()) -> I get Select *
.select((alias.fields() :+ field(name(otherAlias, aColumn)).as(aAlias)):_*) -> I get Select otherAlias.aColumn as aAlias
```

Is there a way to express this with jOOQ?

The rest of the statement seems to work as expected. I am using jOOQ 3.10.7 in Scala and targeting Postgres at the moment and my statement currently looks like this:

```
sql
   .select()
   .from(alias)
   .innerJoin(otherAlias)
   .on(field(name(alias, someColumn)).eq(field(name(otherAlias, someOtherColumn))))
.where(condition)
```

Thanks a lot.

Update: I found a way to express this that seems to work by falling back to plain SQL. But I am still wondering whether there is a better way to express this. This works as a select:

```
 .select((field(""""Alias".*"""), field(name(otherAlias, aColumn)).as(aAlias)):_*) -> I get Select "Alias".*, otherAlias.aColumn as aAlias
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you're using jOOQ 3.11 (which added support for [unqualified asterisks](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/2769) and [qualified asterisks](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/1677)), you can just write

```scala
alias.asterisk()
```

Or even, using [jOOQ's scala extensions](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/getting-started/jooq-and-scala/)

```scala
alias.*
```

This is especially powerful when using the code generator.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick response. Works like a charm!